# JS framework to support Three.js on videogame development

Tags: javascript, graphics, 3d, frameworks, three.js

I'd like to develop 3D videogames using [three.js](http://threejs.org/), but since that library it's for handling graphics only, I'm still need a framework that helps me build the game (define entities, handle events, collision detection, etc).

Is there any framework that could help me out with that?

I read about using [sim.js](http://simjs.com/), but I'm not really sure if that's what I'm looking for.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

IMHO, the answer will much vary depending on what kind of game you want to make.

Because browser-based 3D games still require much attention about how you manage memory, assets, etc, I think the best framework for your game will be the one you build for it.

You *will* keep making tradeoffs between quality and performance, regardless of the framework you use.

Now, to answer your question: there are currently almost none complete three.js-based game framework.
Your best bets, in my opinion, are

- to start from a recognized "base" library like [Physijs](https://github.com/chandlerprall/Physijs) and build your game on top of that
- to start with little bricks done by others, like J.Etienne [three.js extras](https://github.com/jeromeetienne?tab=repositories)
- to start from an open-source "finished" project like [voxeljs](http://voxeljs.com/) or [cubeslam](https://www.cubeslam.com/vkleex)

Basically [look on github](https://github.com/search?q=threejs%20game&type=Repositories&ref=searchresults) to find something approaching your own goal.

Or, if you feel very adventurous, help me on my own cheap framework [here](http://three-arena.com). yes, that was a very shameless plug.